# The laptop that hates linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, laptop, multi-boot

I have a neo q-note m72S (or alternatively 572S) with windows XP. I am trying to install ubuntu on it, but i am unable to. When attempting to install from the disc, or even "try without installing" the computer almost instantly black screens and reboots. On trying to run a nimblex live cd, it freezes at 0% loaded. An ubuntu wubi install successfully installs, but when attempting to boot to the installation it also black screens and reboots. When running the wubi installation in verbose mode, or trying to install without quiet splash, the screen below is presented, freezes, and then reboots. Is there a parameter that I can use to successfully boot to my installation, or indeed install it in the first place?

**Update:** nomodeset parameter and pnpbios=off on boot disc has stopped the freezing and reboot behavior, but just causes it to stall later in the installation

Although specs are difficult to obtain since there's no OS on it, from what I can gather, it came with windows Vista, has a Pentium Dual-core and 1 gb of ram

[image: picture of stall screen]

Comment: I tried Googling the laptop and couldn't find anything about the machine, mainly just places offering drivers, one of which mentioned Win 98.  I get the impression this is ancient hardware, which would suggest possible compatibility or driver issues.  Can you add the hardware specs to your question?

Comment: @fixer1234 edited. Not sure what was talking about windows 98, as it has respectable specs and shipped with vista

Comment: Just get any ThinkPad next time and you won't have any problems with Linux.

Comment: @paradroid yeah, I would not have chosen this laptop for myself. It was donated as part of a project where we install Linux on old laptops